# Change Android layout without recompiling

Tags: android, layout, dynamic, recompile

I want to allow users to set some layout parameters in an external file, that will be reloaded each time by the application, and wonder if there's a simple way of doing it.

I don't want to define the entire layout in code, but only some specific parameters.
I can extract the parameters from xml to dimens file, but I don't know if there's a way to override this file at runtime. Maybe there's some other ways.

Comment: You can use the `SharedPReferences`. The dimens file(s) **can't be written**.

Comment: I need to read the data from external file so SharedPreferences won't help. I can just read values and then override in code the values I read from xml, just wondered if there's any mechanism I can use without writing extra code.

Comment: `without writing extra code` **NO**.